# Тире или запятая после вводных конструкций

Tags: пунктуация

...Да и погода была чудесной!..Одним словом (?) хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

Вводное слово в данном случае обособляется запятой: **Одним словом, хорошо**

**Пример:** Да и погода была чудесной!..Пора обновления, начало начал, время надежд, любви, желаний, светлых дум и мечтаний. **Одним словом, весна.** [Весенний призыв (2004) // «Экран и сцена», 2004.05.06]

**Запятая или тире?**

Вот в этом примере (про погоду)  тире неуместно, **вводное слово здесь такое "**незаметное**" (на него не падает логическое ударение),   его даже можно пропустить и сказать просто: "Весна!"

**При постановке тире делается пауза и вводное слово логически выделено.** Такая запись обычно уместна в публицистике, когда сообщается ряд позитивных фактов и подводится итог — "одним словом".

Answer (score 0):

**одним словом**
2. Вводное выражение. То же, что «короче говоря, словом». Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми.
[**Словарь-справочник по пунктуации**](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/477/%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC)

*– Да, да... Это – хорошо... И – правда? – как-то смело... ново... **одним словом, хорошо!** Да?*
А. И. Куприн. На разъезде

*...оказалось, что 2402 участника проекта в разных странах и даже континентах пробежали 25400 километров: «...**Одним словом — хорошо!**»*
Из статьи "Кто выходит на пробежку 1 января"

*Сами представьте, всегда находишься в окружении разных людей, всегда на какой-нибудь тусовке, всегда кто-то есть рядом с тобой. **Одним словом, здорово!***
И. Тоневицкий. Путь танцующей души

Если тексту хочется придать экспрессии, то поставьте тире; если же нужно закончить повествование на минорной ноте, поставьте запятую. Всё зависит от автора и его восприятия.